# Baum-Welch many possible observations

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models

I have implemented the baum-welch algorithm in python but I am now encountering a problem when attempting to train HMM (hidden markov model) parameters `A`,`B`, and `pi`. The problem is that I have many observation sequences `Y = (Y_1=y_1, Y_2=y_2,...,Y_t=y_t)`. And each observation variable `Y_t` can take on `K` possible values, `K=4096` in my case. Luckily I only have two states `N=2`, but my emission matrix `B` is `N by K` so 2 rows by 4096 columns.

Now when you initialize B, each row must sum to 1. Since there are 4096 values in each of the two rows, the numbers are very small. So small that when I go to compute `alpha` and `beta` their rows eventually approach 0 as `t` increases. This is a problem because you cannot compute `gamma` as it tries to compute `x/0` or `0/0`. How can I run the algorithm without it crashing and without permanently altering my values?

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of your program.

Comment: This reads more like a math problem than a Python problem

Comment: Sounds like you're losing precision, which often happens when you add numbers of very different magnitudes.  I'd try to step through the algorithm and figure out where the precision is lost and somehow mitigate it.  To mitigate it, you'll have to be clever and/or work with more bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the standard HMM scaling problem.  Have a look at "A Tutorial on Hidden Markov Models ..." (Rabiner, 1989), section V.A "Scaling".

Briefly, you can rescale `alpha` at each time to sum to 1, and rescale `beta` using the *same* factor as the corresponding `alpha`, and everything should work.

Comment: This is exactly my problem, I have the Rabiner paper printed out already and will check it out. Thanks!