# Baum-Welch algorithm scaling issue - Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, normalization, hidden-markov-models, numerical-stability

I am implementing Baum-Welch algorithm in Matlab from this wikipedia link : [Baum-Welch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum%E2%80%93Welch_algorithm#Algorithm). It is a part of my volatility forcasting in financial time series.
I have two questions :

**1**: in the last of update step in wikipedia page, It has been told that "These steps are now repeated iteratively **until a desired level of convergence**.".
So how to declare a condition to stop the loop? in addition what variables should be evaluated to see if they are acceptable?

**2**:If you pay attention in the Wikipedia's formulas for `kesi`:

```
kesi = (alhpa(i,t) * a(i,j) * beta(j,t+1) * b(j,t+1) ) / sum over states for alpha(states,T)
```

There are two factors that are scaled in the numerator (`alpha` and `beta`) and one in denominator ( just `alpha` ) . So they will dont cancel each others effect. I have implemented the equations (in a loop that repeats 20 times,for example) and I've done the scaling procedure. but the "transition probability matrix" and "initial distribution" and "emission matrix" gets `NaN` values!!!

I've read this question's answer [Baum-Welch many possible observations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768182/baum-welch-many-possible-observations). I've did scaling based on tutorial mentioned there. 
Here is my code :

```
n = 3;      % number of sataes
T = 20;     % number of observations
%do some initializing things with random values and computing gamma,kesi...
index=20;
while index>=0
pi_star = gamma(:,1)';
P_star = zeros(n,n);
for i_2=1:n
    makhraj = sum(gamma(i_2,:));
    for j=1:n
        sorat = sum(kesi(i_2,j,:));
        P_star(i_2,j) =(sorat) / (makhraj) ;
    end
end
Q_star=zeros(n,T);
for t=1:T
    for i_2=1:n
        makhraj = sum(gamma(i_2,:));
        sorat=0;
        for h=1:T
            if Obs(h) == Obs(t)
                sorat = sorat + (gamma(i_2,t));
            end
        end
        Q_star(i_2,t) = (sorat)/(makhraj);
    end
end
%computing the forward probabilities
for i_2=1:n
    alpha(1,i_2) = pi_star(1,i_2)*Q_star(i_2,1);
end
for t=2:T
    for j=1:n
        alpha(t,j) = (alpha(t-1,:)*(P_star(:,j))) * Q_star(j,t) ;
    end
end
%%% scaling forward probabilities
for t=1:T
    c = 1 / sum(alpha(t,:));
    for i2=1:n
        alpha(t,i2) = alpha(t,i2) * c;
    end
end
%computes backward probabilitis
for t=(T-1):(-1) : 1
    rightVector=Q_star(:,t+1).* beta( t+1 ,:)' ;
    beta ( t , : ) = P_star* rightVector ;
end
%%% scaling backward probabilities
for t=1:T
    d = 1 / sum(beta(t,:));
    for i2=1:n
        beta(t,i2) = beta(t,i2) * d;
    end
end
%computing gamma variable
sigma_ab = zeros(1,T);
for t=1:T
    for j=1:n
        sigma_ab(1,t) = sigma_ab(1,t) + (alpha(t,j)*beta(t,j));
    end
end
for t=1:T
    for j=1:n
        gamma(j,t) = ((alpha(t,j)*beta(t,j))/sigma_ab(1,t));
    end
end
%computing kesi
makhraj_k = zeros(1,T);
for t=1:T
    for i_2=1:n
        makhraj_k(1,t) = makhraj_k(1,t) + alpha(t,i_2);
    end
end
for t=1:T-1
    for i_2=1:n
        for j=1:n
            kesi(i_2,j,t) = (alpha(t,i_2)*P_star(i_2,j)*beta(t+1,j)*Q_star(j,t+1))/makhraj_k(1,t);
        end
    end
end
index = index -1;
end %end while
```

So what should I do now for this scaling problem? is this `NaN` values because scaling issue or something else?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's been a some time since I last worked with HMMs, but you could take a look at Kevin Murphy's [BNT](https://github.com/bayesnet/bnt) and [HMM](http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/HMM/hmm.html) toolboxes. That would be the `dhmm_em` and `mhmm_em` functions that implement the EM algorithm (Baum-Welch) for discrete and continuous cases: https://github.com/bayesnet/bnt/tree/master/HMM. MATLAB also has [`hmmtrain`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hmmtrain.html) in the Statistics Toolbox for the discrete HMM only. You can see how they define the tolerance as stopping criteria.

Comment: of course *Lawrence Rabiner*'s seminal paper is indispensable here. There's also a paper: "Numerically Stable Hidden Markov Model
Implementation" on scaling factors and numerical stability of HMM implementations

Comment: @Amro thank you I will take a look at that. but  I should change this code to C and dont want to use pre-defined matlab functions. I've saw Kevin Murphy's BNT and HMM toolboxes before, in fact I found that a little complex and confusing and I can not find my first question's answer in that.

Comment: I have found answer to my second question. The `NaN` values appears when the observation sequence grows up. in my case after `T>100`. 
So i thought that the scaling procedures cant respond to my problem, and I used the logarithm space to compare the probabilities. here is the source : "Numerically Stable Hidden Markov Model Implementation" by Tobias P. M ann . I'm still looking for first question's answer.

Comment: that's the same paper I mentioned in my previous comment :) Probabilities are small numbers between 0 and 1, multiplying many probabilities together from long sequences can quickly underflow reaching zero with floating-point arithmetics, so you will likely get a NaN in intermediate calculations somewhere... That paper above suggests working in log-scale with the nice property of `log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b)`

Comment: As for convergence, it is usually decided by checking if the log-likelihood of the data does not improve by much for some number of iterations. So if `LL_new - LL_old < threshold` is true for say 5 iterations then you stop. You decide an acceptable threshold and max number of iterations.